# Issue Using OwlCarousel with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, carousel

I am using vue.js and OwlCarousel and every time I use the v-for with the carousel it doesn't show me the style of the carousel it only show me the Images in column.

this the request to an API:

```
<script>
export default {
  data: {
    videos_p: []
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("xxxxxxxxxxx")
      .then(response => {
        this.videos_p = response.data
        console.log(this.videos_p)
      })
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
  owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 4,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 900,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
        nav: true
      },
      600: {
        items: 3,
        nav: false
      },
      1000: {
        items: 5,
        nav: true,
        loop: false,
        margin: 20
      }
    }
  });

})
</script>
```

and this is the html:

```
  <section id="demos">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
          <div class="item" v-for="video in videos_p">
            <img v-bind:src="video.image_url">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

but every time that I use vue it doesn't show me the carousel it only show me the images in column, but if I use the example like this it works fine:

```
  <section id="demos">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar1">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar1">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar1">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar1">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar1">
      </div> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

any idea where I am making a mistake?????

Comment: Try calling what you have in `$(document).ready` after Vue has finished mounting the structure.

Comment: Do you have any example??? because I add  the function after the mounted() finishied and it doesn't show the images or anything

Comment: Try putting it in `updated()`, that way the carousel will initialize when Vue updates the markup because of the axios request.

Comment: I put the $(document).ready inside of function called it update like you said  function update(){} and still the same.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Vue-nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

What is happening is JS is executing your $().owlCarousel before axios is sending response, because you don't know when the response would be received you need to wait till the response from axios is received and then immediately execute the code in Vue.nextTick();

And the other problem is `this` doesn't points to Vue instance in `axios()` so you need to make a variable and store `this` to it.

In your method, after you calling axios callback, add this:

```
var vm = this; //declare this just BEFORE calling axios();
// The below are inside axios.then()
vm.videos_p = response.data;
Vue.nextTick(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 4,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 900,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
        nav: true
      },
      600: {
        items: 3,
        nav: false
      },
      1000: {
        items: 5,
        nav: true,
        loop: false,
        margin: 20
      }
    }
  });
}.bind(vm));
```

and then **completely** remove your $(document).ready();

I would had gone ahead and made a `method: {}` in VueJS, and call it `installOwlCarousel` and then call it in my `process.nextTick()`.
Something like:

```
data: {
 ....
},
method: {
 installOwlCarousel: function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   //my options
  });
 },
 mounted: function(){
  var vm = this;
  axios.get('...xx..')
   .then((res)=>{
    vm.videos_p = res.data;
    Vue.nextTick(function(){
     vm.installOwlCarousel();
    }.bind(vm));
   })
   .catch((err)=>{
    if(err) console.log(err);
   });
 }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I add "import Vue from 'vue' " on the top before the export default also included your code and It works fine thanks Bro.

Comment: oops I missed that import, I would thought that it was export function. :)

Comment: mmm I am not sure why request me the import but your code works fine.

Comment: I meant I was sorry I didn't notice that you were using Vue with the export method, anyways cheers!

Comment: Also, would you mind marking the answer correct && up voting if it's of some help?

Comment: I mark it like a good aswer but I am Lv.6 it doesn't show the vote, sorry for that

Comment: This can be useful in the future: you can load your data beforeMount an then call pass them to vue-owl-caroussel.